# Может ли объект, находясь в коллекции, узнать, где именно он находится?

Tags: c#, winforms, vb.net

Например есть `ListBox` или `ComboBox`, в помощью метода `Items.Add()` мы добавляем объекты в коллекции этих элементов.

Может ли добавленный объект, узнать изнутри, где он, в `ListBox` или `ComboBox` ?

Я понимаю, что можно создать свойство `Parent` и присвоить ссылку на компонент в который мы добавляем объект, вопрос в том, можно ли без этого обойтись?

Comment: А о каком графическом фреймворке идёт речь? В общем случае ответ отрицательный, но конкретный графический фреймворк может сохранять дополнительную информацию.

Comment: обычный `Windows.Forms`

Comment: *Я понимаю, что можно создать свойство `Parent`* А чем существующие свойство [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx) не устраивает?

Comment: У обычного стандартного класса в VB.NET есть свойство `Parent` ???

Comment: оно есть у класса Control, от которого наследуются элементы

Comment: в вашем случае придется создавать свойство Parent самому, если оно вам нужно. Возможно стоит описать более общую задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить, тогда возможно найдется другой вариант, и объектам не будет нужно знать где они находятся.

Comment: @PetSerAl вы не перепутали коллекцию Controls с коллекцией Items случаем? Для Controls ваше утверждение верно, для Items - нет.

Comment: Нет я не перепутал ничего.

Comment: `Items` у `ComboBox` и `ListBox` принадлежат к разным классам: `Combobox.ObjectCollections` и `ListBox.ObjectCollections`. Не смотря на то, что и там, и там - `ObjectCollections`, они все-таки разные и свойства `owner` или `Parent`не имеют.

В принципе, для любого `Item` в любом из этих компонент можно вызвать и проанализировать `item.GetType().FullName`, тогда станет ясно, в контроле какого класса находится тот или иной `item`.
А вот понять, в каком именно - в **listBox1** или в **listBox2** -- не получится так.

Comment: @BlackWitcher Боюсь вы не поняли вопроса. `item.GetType()` вернет тип самого класса вложенного в коллекцию.